# Способ словообразования слова "путешествие"

Tags: словообразование

А может сложносуффиксальный? http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/путешествие смотрите, там интерфикс между основами и вторая основа состоит из корня и суффикса

Не надо закрывать вопрос, если на него дали неверный ответ!

Кто его плюсует?:)

Answer (score 11):

Слово путешествие образовано суффиксальным способом от глагола путешествовать.

Дополняю.

Dmitry! Наличие соединительной гласной вовсе не свидетельство того, что способ образования -  сложение, как и наличие приставки вовсе не доказательство приставочного способа. (Сравни: черносливовый - суффиксальный способ, забег - бессуфиксный способ) Словообразовательная цепочка для Вашего случая: путь, шествовать - путешествовать - путешествие (Аналогично: приветствовать - приветствие,напутствовать - напутствие,противодействовать - противодействие и т.д. Это типичный способ образования отглагольных существительных.)  А если хочется удостовериться в официальных источниках, смотрите словообразовательные словари, а не WIKI. Например, в двухтомном словаре Тихонова в первом томе в  гнезде номер 1502 вы найдете нужную информацию по слову "путешествие". И еще. Учитесь корректно возражать, пусть даже и заочному собеседнику.

Answer (score 3):

Дело в том, что между языковедами принята такая аксиома, что отглагольные существительные образованы от глаголов. Почему? Ну, во-первых; потому что в подавляющем большинстве случаев это действительно так, и можно построить вполне логичные словообразовательные цепочки (*привет-приветствовать-приветствие; жар-жарить-жарение; мечта-мечтать-мечтания* и т. д.). А во-вторых; даже в тех случаях, когда такие цепочки не построить, искать что появилось раньше курица или яйцо, занятие как правило малоперспективное, поэтому при наличии глагола, считается, что существительное появилось именно от него. Так что Ларf написала, всё верно.

Если брать конкретней, слова "путешествие", то какой смысл у глагола "путешествовать" при отсутствии слова "путешествие"? Сказать " еду(иду) в..." намного быстрее и проще, чем "путешествую в...", в то время как для обозначения состояния нахождения в пути (существительное), других подходящих слов-то и нет. Неслучайно почти все словари дают определение к "путешествовать", как "совершать путешествие". У Афанасия Никитина было "хождение", а не путешествие, что говорит о сравнительно позднем появлении данного слова и ещё о том, что существительное могло быть неологизмом для обозначения литературного жанра, соответственно образоваться сращением 2-х основ. Думаю, похожая история и например со словом "напутствие", так без этого существительного глагол "напутствовать" попросту не имеет смысла.

Однако, несмотря на это повторюсь, что при наличии такого задания в каком-либо тесте или контрольной, лучше производить подобные существительные от глагола. При устной проверке, можно попробовать высказать, приведённые выше соображения, но только если уверены, что преподаватель готов их воспринять.

Comment: отглагольные существительные